# Fetch API with http flutter

Tags: flutter, http

I am trying to fetch api with http package. It is working on postman. It has form-data inside body. I was unable to figure out how we can call form data in header. I will attach postman image for better understanding.

[image]

[image]

My code:

```
Future<LocationDetailsById> locationDetailsByID(BuildContext context,String locationID) async{
      String url = baseUrl + "location/detailsbyid";
      var body = {

        "location_id":int.parse(locationID)};
      Utils.showLoaderDialog(context);
      final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/form-data',
        'Authorization':'Bearer ${Utils.token}',
      }, body: jsonEncode(body)
      );
      print("request $locationID");
      print("response ${response.body}");
      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        Navigator.pop(context);

        return  LocationDetailsById.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));


      }else {
        return Utils.errorDialog(context, "Something went wrong");
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you're body is formatted incorrectly for a form post, it looks like its formatted for an endpoint that accepts a JSON body.

I would format the post body as a `FormData` like this:

```
String url = baseUrl + "location/detailsbyid";
FormData formData = FormData.fromMap(body);
await http.post(url: url, body: formData, headers: {...});
```